# Error when Using Manifest Icon in Localhost: 'Download error or resource isn't a valid image

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to use an icon from the manifest in my web application. The application is hosted locally at `http://localhost:3000`, and I've specified the icon's URL as `http://localhost:3000/logo192.png` in the manifest. However, I'm getting an error that says: "Download error or resource isn't a valid image." I've checked the URL, and the image file is definitely present in the specified location. What could be causing this error and how can I resolve it?

**Details:**

- The web application is being developed locally and is accessible at `http://localhost:3000`.

- I've included a manifest file that specifies various properties including the icon for the application.

- The icon's URL in the manifest is set as `http://localhost:3000/logo192.png`.

- I've verified that the image file `logo192.png` does exist in the root directory of the project.

- Other aspects of the web application, such as HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, seem to be working as expected.

- I've tried opening the icon URL directly in the browser, and it displays the image without any issues.

**Error Message:**

```

```
Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: http://localhost:3000/logo192.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)
```

```

**What I've Tried:**

1. Clearing the browser cache and refreshing the page.

2. Verifying the icon's existence in the specified location.

3. Checking for any typos or errors in the manifest file.

4. Trying different image formats for the icon (e.g., PNG, JPEG).

5. Opening the icon URL directly in the browser to confirm it's accessible.

Despite trying these steps, I'm still encountering the same error. Could someone help me understand why this error might be occurring and how I can go about resolving it? Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

### How to access an image in the root directory

Hi, the correct icon's location is:

```
/logo192.png
```

To access something in the root directory, just use **/**. Do not specify localhost.
When you specify localhost, it's trying to find the image in a folder called localhost.